# Hereditarily Lindelöf spaces with density continuum

Tags: set-theory, gn.general-topology, forcing, continuum-hypothesis

Since there are L-spaces (provably in ZFC), under CH we have regular, hereditarily Lindelöf spaces with density continuum. However, I cannot find an example of such a space under not CH, nor a proof that no such space exists under axioms like MA or PFA. Shelah has a paper on the density of HL spaces, but it is somewhat opaque (I believe it is number 918 in his archive).

Comment: Ma does not exclude the existence of such a space. More precisely, 
using the method of [1] I think that I can prove that  Con(ZFC + $2^{\omega}=\omega_2$ + MA + there is a hereditarily Lindelof space with density $\omega_2$.)

[1]Soukup, L. 
Indestructible properties of S- and L-spaces. 
Topology Appl. 112 (2001), no. 3, 245–257.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and reference! I was working through the Abraham-Todorcevic Handbook article and couldn't find an answer